# Redirect Rewrite for Joomla Root Domain Only?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, joomla

I recently migrated an existing site between two domain names. I created 301 rewrite rules for all existing pages to their new, corresponding links and that appears to be functioning correctly.

Since I individually mapped the link rewrites I didn't have the need to apply a broad redirect all visitors. The issue I am experiencing is that I have not been able to successfully 301 redirect the root (home/index) only. I have tried redirecting / as well as /index.php, but those rules appear to interfere with my other rewrite rules. I'm guessing this has something to do with Joomla's core SEF rewrite rules, but I'm not sure.

Example:
Let's assume this is one of my redirects:
Redirect 301 /oldlink http://www.example.net/newlink

But someone somehow visits /oldlink25 (which doesn't exist and never has). The current setup where I am redirecting /index.php, which is my attempt to redirect the root only, will still redirect this visitor to the new site root. I'd prefer to 404 that visitor, and the old link, at the old domain instead.

Long story short, unless someone visits a link that has an individually declared 301 in the htaccess, how can I redirect visitors that hit the root only and not every visitor that hits any random link without a corresponding rewrite rule?